# What's the difference between 'rxjs/operators' and 'rxjs/internal/operators'?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, rxjs

In an `Angular` project, when I try to import things like `Observable`, or in this case, the `switchMap` operator, I have two options:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

or

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Is also loaded from the internal location, see [operators/index.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/index.ts)

I would suggest using the first one, if the rxjs maintainers change the internal project structure, it won't break your imports.

Answer (score 3):

As of RxJS v7.2.0 it's adviced to import directly from 'rxjs':

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs';
```

As mentioned on the [RxJS website](https://rxjs.dev/guide/importing):

> With RxJS v7.2.0, most operators have been moved to 'rxjs' export site. This means that the preferred way to import operators is from 'rxjs', while 'rxjs/operators' export site has been deprecated.

> Although the old way of importing operators is still active, it will be removed in one of the next major versions.